# Как в JavaScript поделить на %

Tags: javascript

Как в JavaScript поделить на %

```
 var x = ((right_side * 100)/100%).toFixed()
```

Comment: А что значит "поделить на %"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну.... как минимум - учить математику :)))

1. 100% от чего ?:) Процент - понятие, как мы знаем, относительное :))
2. Ответьте на вопрос, как можно делить желтое на вкусное ?:)

и на будущее :))
// Число
var b = 300;
// Кол-во процентов от числа "b"
var e = 30;
// Получим Х, который равен 30% числа b
var x = b  100 * e